# unable to resolve package dependencies

Tags: package-management

I installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS operating system but when I added a new repository with the packages I find this error:

```
Unable to resolve the package dependencies
```

Information requested by @electron:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists ... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information ... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get update
E: The download of some index files failed, they have been ignored, or old ones were used instead.
```

Comment: try to use the following commands and check if they solve your problem
1) sudo dpkg --configure -a     
               2) sudo apt-get install -f  
               3)sudo apt-get update

Comment: in "software & updates" change Ubuntu software from Main Server and Reload .Now try.Similar question [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)